# Código ".exe" parou de funcionar

Tags: array, c++, algoritmo

Ao adicionar novos e-mails aparece a mensagem:

> projeto-email2.exe parou de funcionar

```
int op = 0, quant = 1;
string nomeEmail[quant][2];

while(op != 5){ 
cout << "Selecione a opção desejada\n[1] - Inserir novo nome e e-mail\n[2] - Listar e-mails\n[3] - Consultar e-mail\n";
cout << "[4] - Deletar e-mail\n[5] - Finalizar programa\n";
cin >> op;
        if(op == 1){            
            cout << "\n\nQuantos e-mails você deseja inserir?\n";
            int n;
            cin >> n;
            for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
                cout << "Insira o novo endereço de e-mail, e, em seguida, o nome do usuário:\n";
                cin >> nomeEmail[quant - 1][0] >> nomeEmail[quant - 1][1];
                cout << "Este é o e-mail de número: " << quant << "\n\n";
                quant++;
        }}
```

[image: Código dando erro]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você está criando o *array* (do jeito que se faz em C e não C++) logo no início do código com o tamanho 1. Depois você tenta preencher esse *array* `n` vezes, ou seja, depois que o fizer na primeira vez já encheu o *array* e qualquer acesso adicional potencialmente dará problema, até mesmo quebrando a aplicação porque invade a memória que não está reservada para isto. Então a solução é declarar o *array* só depois que você já sabe qual é o valor de `n`, aí poderá colocar a quantidade de posições necessárias para fazer o preenchimento. Esqueça toda essa variável `quant` ela só causa problemas, só precisa de `n` e `i`.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int op = 0;
    while (op != 5) { 
        cout << "Selecione a opção desejada\n[1] - Inserir novo nome e e-mail\n[2] - Listar e-mails\n[3] - Consultar e-mail\n";
        cout << "[4] - Deletar e-mail\n[5] - Finalizar programa\n";
        cin >> op;
        if (op == 1) {            
            cout << "\n\nQuantos e-mails você deseja inserir?\n";
            int n;
            cin >> n;
            string nomeEmail[n][2];
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                cout << "Insira o novo endereço de e-mail, e, em seguida, o nome do usuário:\n";
                cin >> nomeEmail[i][0] >> nomeEmail[i][1];
                cout << "Este é o e-mail de número: " << i + 1 << "\n\n";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/J55SqD). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/@maniero/GetMailscpp). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/Algorithm/GetMails.cpp).

Comment: Opa, Maniero! Obrigado pela resposta! Implementei a sua sugestão de tirar o quant e meu código está muito mais simples.